# Is it possible to discard incoming packets based on (a dynamically changing set of) IP address(es) on Linux from C/C++ code?

Tags: c++, linux, networking

I am looking into the possibility of filtering incoming UDP traffic based on IP addresses on a Linux machine, discarding packets completely that match any of the filter addresses. The set of IP addresses I am interested in is dynamically (and frequently) changing and is not known a priori. Packets that are deemed to be discarded should skip all further processing. I can grant CAP_NET_RAW capability to the process but do not want to write my own driver or modify the kernel.

### Background information

A practical approach I am using for compactly representing a large set of IP addresses is a Bloom filter. This approach is already used by a dynamic packet filtering approach implemented as a device driver:

http://luca.ntop.org/Blooms.pdf

However, I have user-level code and have no means to tweak the kernel or write a device driver of my own.

Similarly, I do already have a solution that sniffs packets based on IP addresses in an efficient manner based on a PF_PACKET socket and an RX_RING, as is done in netsniff-ng:

http://netsniff-ng.org/

My approach is the extension of the capture mechanism in netsniff (or tcpdump or Wireshark) extended with the Bloom filter principle to get more compact Berkeley Packet Filter (BPF) programs. This works excellently but with the side effect that even if the filter discards the packet (and thus it does not appear in RX_RING), it still continues its journey in the kernel. Eventually, given there are no open sockets for much of the filtered traffic (which is mostly synthesized, as if by netsniff's trafgen) received, ICMP `destination-unreachable` messages are generated.

The question, formulated in a different way is whether there is a C/C++ approach to selectively discard traffic based on custom code (e.g. with a Bloom filter) in an early stage of network stack processing?

I have looked at approaches based on iptables but managing firewall rules via iptables-restore seems far too cumbersome for the scenario. Also, the addresses are not contiguous sets of IP addresses and would thus lead to a long list of separate addresses to test against.

Efficiency is a critical aspect due to the high volume of traffic involved.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to play with `iptables` perhaps using `libipq` and `libiptc` libraries.

Comment: +1. About efficiency: redirecting all the traffic to the userspace and back to undergo inspection may still be less efficient than tuning the kernel netfilter through iptables.

Comment: I am somewhat concerned about libiptc based on http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/FAQ/netfilter-faq-4.html#ss4.5 but libnetfilter_queue might seem a promising approach I should look into.

Answer (score 0):

This answer wont provide much help regarding selectively discarding traffic, but instead of the Bloom filter, you could consider using a [Patricia trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patricia_trie) (Radix Tree) for the IP address representation and lookups? At work, we have to store and lookup large sets of dynamic IP addresses and ranges and have found the Patricia trie to be among the most efficient.

BTW I tried loading the Bloom link, and it wont load for me.

Comment: Currently, I use SO_ATTACH_FILTER with a PF_PACKET socket to register a BPF program, which is interpreted code with an extremely simple instructions set. BPF programs are far too low-level to permit more complex data structures, not even a backwards jump is possible. Looking up items in a Bloom filter, however, is a matter of computing a hash and indexing in an array, simple enough to fit into a BPF program. If the filtering code ends up at the C++ level, a radix tree might be a better solution though.